# android - connect to web service

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services, asmx, somee

I'm try to connect android application to a web service uploaded on somee.

I have the following problem :

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

**the web service code :**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.n-m.somee.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"workstation id=WSDatabase.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=***;pwd=***;data source=WSDatabase.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=WSDatabase ");
    [WebMethod]
    public string get_name(String pssw)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select username from users where pssw="+pssw, con);
        string rd =(string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        con.Close();
        return rd;
    }
}
```

**I added the following line to manifest file:**

**  MainActivity.java file**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected String namespace="http://www.n-m.somee.com/";
protected String url="http://www.n-m.somee.com/WebService1.asmx";
protected String SOAPAction="http://www.n-m.somee.com/get_name";
protected String method_name= "get_name";

TextView user_name;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}


public void goButton(View v)
{
    user_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //allow internet
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    //create soap object
    SoapObject soapObject=new SoapObject(namespace,method_name);
    soapObject.addProperty("pssw", "1234");

    //create envelop
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

    //Rrquest get data from webservice and set it into soapobject

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

    try {
        transport.call(SOAPAction, envelope);

        // get data
        SoapPrimitive output=(SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //set data into control
        user_name.setText("pssw: "+output.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

I appreciate any help
thank you

Comment: Seems like some error with your database connection.

Comment: the problem solved when I put the connection string in web.config and change SOAPAction to  SOAPAction="http://www.n-m.somee.com/get_name";
thanks for your help but now the error is :failed to connect to www.n-m.somee.com/208.94.246.108 (port 80) after 20000ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urls were a bit wrong. This is what I used,

```
protected String namespace = "http://www.nourhan-m.somee.com/";
protected String url = "http://www.nourhan-m.somee.com/WebService1.asmx";
protected String SOAPAction = "http://www.nourhan-m.somee.com/get_name";
protected String method_name = "get_name";
```

I made some modification to your code to make it work.

```
public String callService(String username) {
    //create soap object and add params to it
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method_name);
    request.addProperty("pssw", username);

    //create envelop
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    //set request to envelope
    envelope.bodyOut = request;

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    transport.debug = true;
    try {
        transport.call(SOAPAction, envelope);
        Log.e("OUT", transport.requestDump);
        return transport.responseDump;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is how I invoked the method,

You can invoke it as follows,

```
final String username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("OUT", callService(username));
    }
}).start();
```

I got an empty response, maybe it's because I didn't give a valid username. Have a look at it. Cheers :)

Comment: thank you for your help .,
but your code or my code after modification return null 
I don't know why , I tried the web service sql query on web host and it returns value

Comment: the web service take pssw and return username
try "1234"

Comment: It gave me nothing.. `<get_nameResponse xmlns="http://www.nourhan-m.somee.com/" />`. Empty response. :(

Comment: @n-m In you database, is `pssw` field `varchar`?

Comment: pssw field is nvarchar

Comment: Try change your query like this, `select username from users where pssw='"+pssw+"'"`

Comment: @n-m Any luck with the query?

Comment: thanks for your interest
when the parameter value  included in the webservice method like:
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select username from users where pssw="1212", con); 
it works correctly

but when I pass the parameter value "pssw" through android app it returns null value

Comment: @n-m Change your code like this, `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select username from users where pssw='"+pssw+"'", con);`

Comment: public string get_pssw(String user_n)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select pssw from users where username=' "+ user_n +" ' ", con);

            string rd = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            con.Close();
            return rd;
        }
the problem still exist

Comment: @n-m Is the service offline now?

Comment: yes, I deleted the previous one , now it's name is "AndroidWS" and
 METHOD_NAME = "get_pssw";

Comment: @n-m I got the output! Try the same code I posted. Update the method name and parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry for disturbance. it doesn't work with me
please acknowledge me if thes lines are true:

callService("nourhan");

        request.addProperty("username", username);

Comment: @n-m I have written `request.addProperty("user_n", username);` instead of `request.addProperty("username", username);`.

Comment: Wow! At last. I'm glad i could help. Good luck. :)